# Get column-wise maximums from a NumPy array

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 2D array, say

```py
x = np.random.rand(10, 3)

array([[ 0.51158246,  0.51214272,  0.1107923 ],
   [ 0.5210391 ,  0.85308284,  0.63227215],
   [ 0.57239625,  0.06276943,  0.1069803 ],
   [ 0.71627613,  0.66454443,  0.56771438],
   [ 0.24595493,  0.01007568,  0.84959605],
   [ 0.99158904,  0.25034553,  0.00144037],
   [ 0.43292656,  0.9247424 ,  0.5123086 ],
   [ 0.07224077,  0.57230282,  0.88522979],
   [ 0.55665913,  0.20119776,  0.58865823],
   [ 0.55129624,  0.26226446,  0.63070611]])
```

Then I find the indexes of maximum elements along the columns:

```py
indexes = np.argmax(x, axis=0)

array([5, 6, 7])
```

So far so good.

But how do I actually get those elements? That is, how do I get `?some_operation?(x, indexes) == [0.99158904, 0.9247424, 0.88522979]`?

Note that I need both the indexes and the associated values.

The best I could come up with was `x[indexes, range(x.shape[1])]`, but it looks kinda complicated and inefficient. Is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: That is THE idiomatic way.  But also look at the new `np.take_along_axis`

Comment: You should be using `x[indexes, np.arange(x.shape[1])]` for perf..

Comment: @hpaulj can you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept? A full solution example, including any efficiency tips.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.amax` to find max value along an axis.

Using your example (`x` is the original array in your post):

```
In[1]: np.argmax(x, axis=0)
Out[1]: 
array([5, 6, 7], dtype=int64)

In[2]: np.amax(x, axis=0)
Out[2]: 
array([ 0.99158904,  0.9247424 ,  0.88522979])
```

[Documentation link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

Comment: Of course, but that's inefficient. We should be able to do better than traverse the entire matrix (which will be huge) twice: once in `argmax`, and then again in `max`.

Comment: you may simply do pass the argmax results as indexes to get the values like this 
```
idxs = np.argmax(x, axis=0)
values= np.array([x[idxs[i],i] for i,col in range(len(idxs))])
```